# Is w3schools's file upload code secure?

Tags: php, html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload-file.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the php code for file upload..I want to use this php code which i got from w3schools..do you think this is a safe code for file upload? this is the simplest code I found which works very great.. I have tried a couple of codes from other sources but I couldn't get them work....any idea?

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2097152)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
}
if($_FILES['file']['size'] >  2097152 )  //2mb

echo 'File over 2MB';

else
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
"images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
echo "Stored in: " . "images/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}
}
}
else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your requirements for the script? What it should do exactly (and thus what should it stop)? Without exact requirements it hard to tell if the things the code allows should or should not be allowed.

Comment: `any idea` - yes, learn yourself about file upload in php, write your own code, learn about security, fix bugs in your code, etc. everything other than taking third party code without fully understanding what it does.

Comment: You should validate that the images are in fact valid. Checking the filename isn't enough.

Comment: @complex857 I just want to accept images from the user and nothing else...

Comment: @user1929075 to ensure you only get images you can try to read the file with the GD library and check the image dimensions. If it comes back as `0` or unable to read the image then it's not an image file.

Answer (score 6):

It's better than nothing, but I wouldn't say it's ***secure***.  Maybe ***more secure than nothing at all***.

There are a number of bits of malware that infect images, and while the code will prevent you from uploading anything other than files with an image extension, it does nothing to strip out malware, or check the actual bytes being uploaded.

Theoretically, an executable could be renamed from myapp.exe to myapp.jpg to put a bad file on your server, and additional exploits could be done to rename it back and infect either your server, or some unwary client.

Recommended reading: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unrestricted_File_Upload

This type of protection falls under "**Using White-List for Files’ Extensions**", which is considered "weak" on this particular OWASP page.

---

Also, as MrCode said in the comments above, you can try to read the file with the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) and check the image dimensions. If it comes back as 0 or unable to read the image then it's not an image file.  THis is an additional layer of security not mentioned in the articles I linked to.  It's also something I do in practice in .NET, using the System.Drawing namespace.  Credit to MrCode, as I'm not a PHP developer, and didn't know how to do this in PHP.  Thanks again!

Comment: thanks for the help..do you know any site which has ready code for use like the w3schools?

Comment: Not that I'd trust.  I know this is completely unhelpful, but if you're going to be uploading files, in my opinion, you MUST learn to do it securely.  That means no shortcuts, and research.  Otherwise you're putting your visitors at risk.

Comment: In the spirit of being helpful, however, this is a good place to start learning (other than the OWASP site, which is THE resource for secure web development.)  http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/01/secure-file-upload-in-php-web-applications/

Comment: The code itself is secure in that it will only write files with an image extension. If you have some catastrophic vulnerability on your server like your example of being able to rename files on a remote server then this upload code is the least of your problems.

Comment: @MrCode - would you be upset if I incorporated your comment  above about the GD Library into my answer? Or you could post that as a part of a standalone answer of your own. It's ***really*** a good idea to do this over and above the normal "rules" of checking extension, mime, storing it outside your web directory, etc. I do something similar in my ASP.NET websites as part of my approach to handling image uploads.

Comment: @DavidStratton no problem, go ahead :)